# Clean alert modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, view

I have a problem with a modal.

The code for the modal is:

```
 <div id="alert-modal-pick" class="alert alert-success hidden" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" onclick="$('#alert').addClass('hidden');">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
    <div id="alert-text-modal-pick"></div>
 </div>
```

I want to clear the message when I close the modal.

For achieve this, I use:

```
$('#alert-modal-pick').empty();
```

but not delete full alert.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: better be make empty div you have post a message not the whole module.

Comment: Why aren't you using `$("#alert-text-modal-pick")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if you add the hidden class? Like this:

```
$('#alert-modal-pick').empty().addClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, just use

```
$('#alert-text-modal-pick').empty();
```

It will clear your modal content, not its header.